# Static Code Analysis - Old style expression C++

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis

Using Helix QAC, I'm doing some static code analysis. Maybe is the tools it self or I'm just stupid but I get as a message "**This expression uses old style casts**" for this piece of code

```
vfc::abs(perPacket.DataItemBuffer_st.m_mountAngleIndicator.m_el.value())
     > (ABSOLUT_LIMIT_ELE * static_cast<vfc::float32_t>(DEG_TO_RAD))
```

Here is the actual casting done:

```
static_cast<vfc::float32_t>(DEG_TO_RAD)

static constexpr vfc::float32_t ABSOLUT_LIMIT_ELE 
#define DEG_TO_RAD ((FLOAT)0.017453292F) - This is coming from .h file.
```

The problem apparently is in the DEG_TO_RAD and how is it casted, that was of cast is OK for .c code. When I remove the cast (FLOAT) the warning disappears.. Is there a way to do this and still keep the cast in .c file?

Comment: What is `ABSOLUT_LIMIT_ELE`? What is `DEG_TO_RAD`?

Comment: static constexpr vfc::float32_t ABSOLUT_LIMIT_ELE
#define DEG_TO_RAD   ((FLOAT)0.017453292F)

Both of those are floats 
But still I thought the casting is correct..

Comment: Technically the cast in (FLOAT)0.017453292F isn't required, but its still an old style cast

Comment: Start from checking documentation of the tool. It should explain when this warring is triggered. For me it looks like you've mismatch line where it is reported and as a result provided incorrect fragment of code, since there is no C-style casting.

Comment: Please don't post such details in comment, edit your question to include it instead. Preferably you should have created a proper [mre] to begin with.

Comment: The cast simply isn't needed, neither in C nor in C++. The `F` suffix in `0.017453292F` already makes it a `float` value. Unless the macro `FLOAT` expands to something other than `float`?